# CSS backdrop-filter does not work with transition

Tags: css

I have a modal for which I have created a backdrop. I want the backdrop to blur everything behind it, but since while showing the modal, there are some FPS drops and looks a bit laggy, I have decided to apply a transition with a delay to it. Unfortunately, the transition doesn't seem to apply to the backdrop-filter property for a reason I was not able to detect.

Here is the **CSS** applied to the backdrop:

```
.Backdrop {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
    transition: backdrop-filter 500ms 2s;
}
```

With this CSS applied, the application of the backdrop-filter property still happens instantly at the moment when the modal is shown. What am I missing?

Comment: Use ``filter: blur()`` instead.

Comment: @AmirrezaAmini that would blur the content on the backdrop, not what's behind it, therefore would not work as desired.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) enable you to define the transition between two states of an element. Your backdrop never changed state (it had the property `backdrop-filter: blur(2px)` since the page was loaded), so the transition doesn't take effect.

What you're looking for is an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation):

```css
.backdrop {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  
  animation: blur-in 500ms 2s forwards; /* Important */
}

/* Let's define an animation: */
@keyframes blur-in {
  from {
    backdrop-filter: blur(0px);
  }
  to {
    backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  }
}
```

```html
Some text for testing the blur.
<div class="backdrop"></div>
```