# Backdrop Filter Style Being Applied After Animation

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, framer-motion, css-filters, backdrop

To further understand React I have created a project using `react-router-dom`, `styled-components` and `framer-motion`.

My versions are like so.

`package-json:`

```
    ....
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.7.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    ....
```

My modal has a simple animation with opacity and the container has `backdrop-filter: blur(10px)` applied to it. I want the blur effect to be applied as soon as the fading in of the modal starts. As it is now, the animation is carried out and only after is the backdrop-filter applied. I find this strange, as all other styles, such as `background-color`, are applied from the moment the animation starts.

My component `Modal.js`:

```
import { IntroModal, ModalContainer } from './Modal.styled';
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion';
import { IoMdClose } from 'react-icons/io';

const Modal = ({ isOpen, toggleModal, closeOnOutsideClick, children }) => {
  const modalRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
      if (
        closeOnOutsideClick &&
        modalRef.current &&
        !modalRef.current.contains(event.target)
      ) {
        toggleModal();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    return () => {

      document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [modalRef, closeOnOutsideClick, toggleModal]);
  const closeButtonStyle = {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: '1.5rem',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    filter: 'drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #000)',
  };
  !isOpen
    ? (document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden')
    : (document.body.style.overflow = 'auto');
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      !isOpen && (
      <motion.div
        style={isOpen ? { display: 'none' } : null}
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
        key={isOpen}
      >
        <IntroModal>
          <ModalContainer ref={modalRef}>
            <button onClick={toggleModal}>
              <IoMdClose style={closeButtonStyle} />
            </button>
            {children}
          </ModalContainer>
        </IntroModal>
      </motion.div>
      )
    </AnimatePresence>
  );
};
export default Modal;
```

`Modal.styled.js`:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const IntroModal = styled.div`
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 11;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

    button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0.3rem;
      right: 0.3rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      border: none;
      background: transparent;
      transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
      &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
    }

    img {
      width: 50%;
      box-shadow: 0 0 15px #000;
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }

    p {
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1rem;
      padding: 0 1rem;
    }
`;

export const ModalContainer = styled.div`
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: rgba(38, 50, 50, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 1rem 0.2rem 0.5rem;
  border-top: 0.7px solid #b6b6b666;
  border-right: 0.7px solid #8e8e8e66;
  border-bottom: 0.7px solid #000;
  border-left: 0.7px solid #77777766;
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 #000;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: inherit;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    width: 80vw;
    height: 80vh;
  }
`;

export const ModalWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25%;
  font-size: 2rem;
`;
```

Here is a gif of the appearance of it now:

[image: Clicking on modal]

I have tried to apply the styles directly to the component, eg `style={backdropFilter: blur(10px)`, and also including it in the animation like so (tried both in outer `motion.div` and `ModalContainer` separately):

```
      <motion.div
        style={isOpen ? { display: 'none' } : null}
        initial={{ opacity: 0, backdropFilter: 'blur(0px)' }}
        animate={{ opacity: 1, backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)' }}
        exit={{ opacity: 0, backdropFilter: 'blur(0px)' }}
        key={isOpen}
      >
        <IntroModal>
          <motion.ModalContainer ref={modalRef}
              initial={{ opacity: 0, backdropFilter: 'blur(0px)' }}
              animate={{ opacity: 1, backdropFilter: 'blur(10px)' }}
              exit={{ opacity: 0, backdropFilter: 'blur(0px)' }}
              key={isOpen}
          >
            <button onClick={toggleModal}>
              <IoMdClose style={closeButtonStyle} />
            </button>
            {children}
          </motion.ModalContainer>
        </IntroModal>
      </motion.div>
```

Any tips and advice much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can animate `backdrop-filter: blur`, so what you are only seeing two states of it - `blur(0)` and `blur(10px)` instead of all the intermediate animation steps, so it looks like it is applied after the other transitions complete.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785743/how-to-animate-backdrop-filter) suggests animating from `backdrop-filter: blur(10px) opacity(0);` to `backdrop-filter: blur(4px) opacity(1);` since `backdrop-filter: opacity` can be animated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I understand that backdrop-filter is not animated, I have backdrop-filter applied, I don't want to animate blur - only animate the opacity of the blurred div, which I wish to be blurred from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the problem comes from CSS or Framer-Motion.
But if the problem blames to the Framer-Motion, I guess you can use React-Transition-Group to implement this animation and maybe the problem would be solved.

Comment: If you need clarifying information it should be asked in a comment

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35291133)

Answer (score 0):

After some research on my own, I found that any opacity != 1 could cause blur effect disappear, it blames to CSS. I guess the workaround is change the opacity in other ways, like a mask or something.

Answer (score 0):

With Framer Motion, if you use AnimatePresence to "hide" the component, which already has backdrop filter applied. You can avoid the POP in caused by opacity. The downside being you remove the node from the dom. But depending on your use case this might be suitable.

```
export const MastheadMenuCard = ({
  children,
  className
}: {
  children: ReactNode
  className?: string
}) => {
  const { navOpen, setNavOpen } = useAppContext()

  const item = {
    hidden: { y: 4 },
    visible: { y: 0 }
  }

  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
      {navOpen && (
        <motion.div
          animate={navOpen ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}
          className={cn('pointer-events-auto rounded-lg p-8 px-12 frosted-glass', className)}
          exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
          initial="hidden"
          transition={{ opacity: { duration: 0.4 }, y: { duration: 0.1 } }}
          variants={item}
        >
          {children}
        </motion.div>
      )}
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```